# Internal Frame Listeners doesn't work with singleton enum function

Tags: java, user-interface

I have the following code where I made singleton/enum manager so it keeps track of the number of internal frames that have been opened and I can get information from anyone of the frames when the user clicks on it (which activates the frame). But I don't know how to make this work because I want when a user clicks suppose on the 1st frame (out of 5 frames that have been opened), I want a save button to be enabled. When none of the windows are activated I want the button to be disabled. I put an internal frame listener and a component listener but none of them work. I was hoping if anyone could tell me where I am going wrong.

Here is the code:

```
 public class Manager implements ActionListener, InternalFrameListener, ComponentListener{

private static int openFrameCount =0;
ImagePlus image;
private String tile;
final String SHOW ="show";
static ImageWindow m;
JMenuItem showInfo;
static JMenuItem save;
static JDesktopPane desktop;
InfoGui in;

public Manager(ImagePlus img, String title, JDesktopPane desktop, JMenuItem save){
    image = img;
    this.desktop = desktop;
    this.tile = title;
    this.save = save;
}

public enum WindowManager {

    INSTANCE;
    public MyInternalFrame frame;
    private Map<ImagePlus, List<MyInternalFrame>> mapWindows;

    private WindowManager(){

        mapWindows = new HashMap<>(25);

    }

    public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

        static final int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;
        public MyInternalFrame(String title, ImagePlus img, JMenuItem save) {
            super(title, true,true, true, true);
            setSize(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight());

            // Set the window's location.
            setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition * openFrameCount);
            save.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public JInternalFrame createWindowFor(ImagePlus image) {

        List<MyInternalFrame> frames = mapWindows.get(image);

        if (frames == null) {
            frames = new ArrayList<>(25);
            mapWindows.put(image, frames);
        }

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        ImageCanvas c = new ImageCanvas(image);
        c.getImage();

        //panel2.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(c.getImage())));
         m = new ImageWindow(image);

        Image n = new Image();
        //frame = new MyInternalFrame(title, img, save,m);
        //ImageCanvas c = m.getCanvas();
        ImagePlus im = new ImagePlus();
        im.setImage(image);

        frame = new MyInternalFrame(image.getTitle(), image, save);
        m.centerNextImage();
        image.getCanvas().setScaleToFit(true);

        panel.add(m.getCanvas());
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.add(panel);
        frames.add(frame);

        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        frame.setAutoscrolls(true);
        frame.setOpaque(true);
        desktop.add(frame);
        try {
                frame.setSelected(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {

        }

        return frame;

    }

    public List<MyInternalFrame> getFromFor(ImagePlus image) {

        JInternalFrame frame = null;
        return mapWindows.get(image.getTitle());

    }

}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SADAPP.Manager.WindowManager.MyInternalFrame m = (SADAPP.Manager.WindowManager.MyInternalFrame) WindowManager.INSTANCE.createWindowFor(image);
}



@Override
public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    save.setEnabled(true);
}



@Override
public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    save.setEnabled(false);
}



@Override
public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    save.setEnabled(false);
}



@Override
public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    save.setEnabled(false);
}



@Override
public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    save.setEnabled(true);
}



@Override
public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    save.setEnabled(false);
}



@Override
public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    save.setEnabled(true);
}



@Override
public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    save.setEnabled(false);
}



@Override
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Rectangle r = WindowManager.INSTANCE.frame.getBounds();

    m.getCanvas().fitToWindow(r);
    System.out.println("resized- the real one");
}



@Override
public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

Comment: I also implemented the Internal frame Listener and ComponentListener on the enum (singleton) but its still doesn't work. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods of the InternalFrameListener and ComponentListener interfaces won't be called merely by existing. You need to call [`addInternalFrameListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#addInternalFrameListener-javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener-) or [`addComponentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addComponentListener-java.awt.event.ComponentListener-) on the frame to tell it about your listener.

For example, in the constructor of MyInternalFrame, you want something like:

```
this.addInternalFrameListener(someInstanceOfTheManagerObject);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I forgot that. Thank you again!